# Include dates in a membership sign up form

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I have a contribution page set up to allow people to sign up for a new membership or renew a membership. The membership is a fixed period type. The user must either create an account or log in. I would like the Membership price option to show the dates (or year) that they are signing up for. Thus if they are a new member, it would should the current period (e.g. "2019 Membership") and if they log in as a current renewing member, it would show that future Membership dates they are choosing (e.g. "2020 Membership"). This is on a Wordpress site.

Comment: It may not help but .... did you know that you can add different text to show on the contribution page that will depend on whether the logged in user (or contact using a checksum) has an existing membership (ie is a renewal) v a New membership.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion that's somewhat helpful but doesn't solve the problem in a future-proof way. I could manually each year update it so that the renewal user sees next year and a new user sees this year. How do I do this?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem that upon checkout, the user doesn't know which year they are paying for, unless they can remember what it said on the previous page help text.

Comment: You may want to edit your Question to add that last info if it is extra info not including in your original text

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to create a wordpress page

For logged in member you should be able to find his contact ID and membership ID

Using some PHP code you can select civicrm_membership table from civicrm database. Which will provide you with membership End date and you can use that to display to the member before renewing

I guess this helps !!!

If you need more help please let me know

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I should mark this as the answer if I didn't end up using it. It is still probably the best solution, but we ended up avoiding the problem altogether in a different way.

Comment: @ScottWilton It would be better to add your solution as answer - In future people will have two different solution for a single problem